# Same scale but different height for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

i struggle to set the same scale to the y-axis of two subplots in matplotlib. 
I can come quite close doing this manually. But is there an option to take the very same scale for the two subplots?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib

x=np.array([0,1,2,4])/4.
y1=[0.5,0.5,1.0,1.5]
y2=[0,1,2,4]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8.5))
ax1=plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.yticks([0.5,1,1.5])
plt.grid()
ax2=plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.yticks([0.5,1,1.5])
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
ratio1=(ax1.get_xlim()[1]-ax1.get_xlim()[0])/(ax1.get_ylim()[1]-ax1.get_ylim()[0])
ratio2=(ax2.get_xlim()[1]-ax2.get_xlim()[0])/(ax2.get_ylim()[1]-ax2.get_ylim()[0])

aspectratio=0.5
ratio_default= ratio2*aspectratio
ax1.set_aspect(ratio_default)
plt.savefig('demo.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ar=ax2.get_position().bounds

ar=((ar[0]-ar[2])/(ar[1]-ar[3]))

aspectratio=ar
```

does the work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set `set_ylim` to ensure the axis are the same for both `ax1` and `ax2` and use `subplot2grid` to lay the two plots out on a grid formation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib

x = np.array([0,1,2,4])/4.
y1 = [0.5,0.5,1.0,1.5]
y2 = [0,1,2,4]
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8.5))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=1)
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.yticks([0.5,1,1.5])
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1.5])

plt.grid()

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=3, rowspan=2)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.yticks([0.5,1,1.5])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 1.5])
plt.grid()

plt.tight_layout()

ratio1 = (ax1.get_xlim()[1]-ax1.get_xlim()[0])/(ax1.get_ylim()[1]-ax1.get_ylim()[0])
ratio2 = (ax2.get_xlim()[1]-ax2.get_xlim()[0])/(ax2.get_ylim()[1]-ax2.get_ylim()[0])

plt.savefig('demo.png')
plt.show()
```

The aspect ratio is then not required. This gives you an output as follows:
[image]

Comment: I could do this, however I only want to show the region of interest of the upper subplot by changing its height.

Comment: You can use `subplot2grid` to lay the top sub plots out on a grid formation. Then an aspect ratio is not required.